# Passing Promise as parameter doesn't trigger then or fail callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Even though i am able to pass promise as parameter into error function, it does not trigger then & error function on the caller.?

if i change the code to put the AJAXError function inline, everything works fine.

Is it possible to pass around the promise around as parameter and still be able to trigger back then and fail on the caller up in the chain.

**NOTE : promise is returned from palletizerService.addSerialNumberToPallet but  but resolved/rejected in a different function AjaxFailed.**

```
palletizerService.addSerialNumberToPallet ('p1','s1')
.then(  function (response){
    console.log('success');
},
function(error){
    console.error(error);
});
```

Hereunder is the service that i am invoking from the above code

```
palletizerService.addSerialNumberToPallet = function (palletID, serialNumber) {
var deferred = $q.defer();

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    methodName: methodName,
    deferred: deferred.promise,
    data: "palletID=" + palletID + "&serialNumber=" + serialNumber, 
    timeout: 20000, // 20 seconds for getting result, otherwise error.
    error: AjaxFailed,
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log("Ajax-finally : " + methodName);
    },
    beforeSend: function (qXHR, settings) {
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("Ajax-Sucess " + methodName);
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }
});

return deferred.promise;
};
```

This is the external function

```
function AjaxFailed(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

try {
    console.error('Ajax-Error in ' + methodName, qXHR.status, qXHR.responseText);

} catch (e) {
    console.log("LocalMethod-Error in " + methodName);
    console.error(e);
}
finally {
    this.deferred.reject(qXHR);
}

}
```

Comment: Would make a lot more sense to use `$http` which already returns a `$q` promise. You are mixing up promise libraries and creating an anti pattern. The jQuery promise isn't the same one as your `$q.defer`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are passing the *promise* as the `.deferred` property of your options object. You cannot resolve/reject promises, they don't have a `.reject` method (and your code should throw when trying to call it). You would instead need to pass the `deferred` object you are holding.

However, this is a bad idea anyway. As `jQuery.ajax` does already return a promise, you should simply assimilate it using `$q.when`:

```
function (palletID, serialNumber) {
    return $q.when($.ajax({
         …
    }));
}
```

(you will be able to omit all `success` and `errror` handlers, angular-promise does take care of them; if you want to add transformations or logging do those on the promise).

Yet that's still not optimal, in fact there hardly is a reason to use `jQuery.ajax` at all. Just use Angular's [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), which also returns an angular promise right away.